# set Oracle Current Timestamp to JPA entity

Tags: spring, oracle, jpa, timestamp, eclipselink

I Have simple question,

I want to set Oracle CURRENT_TIMESTAMP to my JPA entity, I do not want Java to send value.

I tried below but did not work.

```
@Column(name="TMSP", columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", nullable=false)
private Timestamp tmsp;
```

its either inserting null or date I set in java but not the DB date.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30707621/spring-jpa-default-value-for-enum-field-in-enum/30707816#30707816

Comment: This is not helping its for mysql and I need something for Oracle system date using current_date function

Comment: Re-read it to understand what you're doing, and why your solution is not the right solution. Whether you use Oracle or MySQL is irrelevant

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
updatable= false
@Column(name="TMSP", updatable= false, columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", nullable=false)
private Timestamp tmsp;
```