# 'default' is not working in @Column in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Below is my entity class, I have added `default` contraint on my EnumType variable of class. But while the value in the db, it not taking that value and giving `ContraintViolation`.
Entity

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee{   
  @Id
  private String id;
  
  @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
  private String name;
  
  @Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
  private String email;
  
  @Column(name = "language", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(10) default 'ENGLISH'")
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private Language language;
  
}
```

Here, if I remove `nullable` from Language Enum, the language is saved as null. Why is it not taking default value as `ENGLISH`

Comment: Unless you use JPA dynamic-insert, the insert query will include `language=NULL` and your default value will not be taken into account. What you can also do is put the default value on the field of the entity like `private Language language = Language.ENGLISH;`

Comment: @NicoVanBelle I tried setting the language field in entity, it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Since `Language` is of type ENUM, you can use:

```
@Column(name = "language", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "enum('ENGLISH' , 'CHINESE') default 'ENGLISH'")
```

Answer (score 0):

How about initializing your enum property with default value like below?

```
@Column(name = "language", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(10) default 'ENGLISH'")
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private Language language = Language.ENGLISH;
```

[Refer this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30707816/4039231) for more details